# Predicted score of block of pixels

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to send CNN network input a block of pixels, say m*n size and corresponding target is a vector of p*1 dimension. I am using data generator for sending blocks of pixels in each batch and using model.predict in keras. After training the network, my predicted score will give a p*1 dimensional vector. My question is this output for each pixel of test image or for the block of pixels. I need to get one p*1 vector for each block of pixels. How can I do that? Thanks.